# android.widget.TextView.getText() on a null object reference

Tags: android

i'm new to android and here passing data from one fragment to anther but getting an error

```
CallFragment callFragment=new CallFragment();
textView=v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
text=textView.getText().toString();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", text);

callFragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,callFragment).commit();
```

Comment: may be u are referencing wrong id for text view, your code shows editText as id for textView. Cross check your text view id.

Comment: and what error are you getting?

Comment: android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference this error im getting

Answer (score 0):

Your id **editText** may be exist in other layout. So you cant get error on ide or code writing time, but you get error at run time.